# Hubsan x4 drone camera recording black

Tags: quadcopter, cameras

I'm unsure if this is the correct community to ask this question (vs. [Electronics](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) or [Aviation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange, for example), but I recently purchased a [Hubsan x4 HD video drone from Amazon.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00D8UO8G6)

This is my second Hubsan drone so I am already familiar with using the recording feature. However, after every recording, the recordings are the correct length, with the correct audio, but the image is black. I tried formatting the micro SD, using different micro SDs, reading up on forums, etc. but nothing seems to do the trick.

Is mine defective, or has someone had this issue and has been able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Hubsan is a proprietary drone if I am right. But, there are several reasons why black-outs can happen.

1. The image-sensor/camera may be faulty (The photosensitive material may not be generating signals through photo-voltaic effect).
2. There may be proprietary protocols which may drop frames if parity checks are failing and faulty image-capture can be causing this.
3. Problems with software - This may be due to problems with post-processing and the meta-data is getting retained (may be due to hardware image buffer problems).

This question is vague without videos/descriptions/logs of the same.